# No aparece imagen del background en github pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

He publicado mi página en github pages, mi página tiene una imagen como background, en mi máquina funciona correctamente con la imagen, pero en github pages no se visualiza la imagen.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Cuál es la URL? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].